# remote_addr not returning IPv4 address

Tags: php, xampp, ip-address

I am using xampp on localhost and when I use `$_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]` it returns `::1` (also does this in `phpinfo()`). Why does it do this? I want it to return a normal ip address like 127.0.0.1. My operating system is windows vista.

Answer (score 10):

`::1` is an [IPv6 address](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6_address) and an abbreviation for `0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1` that is the [loopback address](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4291#section-2.5.3) to the local machine. So `::1` is the same as `127.0.0.1` only via IPv6 instead of IPv4.

Answer (score 8):

Your apache is listening for [IPv6](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6) connections by default (`::1` being [local loopback](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4291#section-2.5.3)). If you really just want IPv4, try to disable disable IPv6 connections in your apache configuration:

> If you want Apache to handle IPv4 connections only, regardless of what your platform and APR will support, specify an IPv4 address on all Listen directives, as in the following examples:

```
Listen 0.0.0.0:80
Listen 192.170.2.1:80
```

- http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/bind.html

Answer (score 3):

Go to XAMPP control panel. Open Apache(httpd.conf) which can be found in the first row i.e. Apache Module's Actions. Go to listen (you can Ctrl + F this) which shows 80 (if you have ipv6 active) change it to Listen  `0.0.0.0:80` and you are done.
Restart Apache and you will no longer see `::1` in your browser. This will happily return your localhost i.e. `127.0.0.1`

Answer (score -1):

You have to disable IPv6 support in your OS for apache to stop showing these IPv6 format addresses, when you want the IPv4 format. I disabled IPv6 support and its working as expected now.

The following instructions to disable IPv6 could be helpful, http://support.microsoft.com/kb/929852

Just so you know i followed the steps described in the above link and i'm using Windows 7 not Vista though i doubt there could be any or many differences.

I recently ran into this issue, though i don't ever remember enabling ipv6 support on my system, could be done by Microsoft in one of their updates (maybe).